# Parsing XML data via PHP errors

Tags: xml, soap, php

I'm trying to print out this xml from a API.

```
<XMLSOCCER.COM>
<Match>
<Id>309389</Id>
<Date>2013-08-04T16:00:00+02:00</Date>
<League>Scottish Premier League</League>
<Round>1</Round>
<HomeTeam>St Johnstone</HomeTeam>
<HomeTeam_Id>46</HomeTeam_Id>
<HomeGoals>1</HomeGoals>
<AwayTeam>Hearts</AwayTeam>
<AwayTeam_Id>50</AwayTeam_Id>
<AwayGoals>0</AwayGoals>
<Time>Finished</Time>
<Location>McDiarmid Park</Location>
<HomeTeamYellowCardDetails>83': Murray Davidson;</HomeTeamYellowCardDetails>
<AwayTeamYellowCardDetails>78': Jamie Hamill;</AwayTeamYellowCardDetails>
<HomeTeamRedCardDetails/>
<AwayTeamRedCardDetails/>
</Match>
<Match>
<Id>309390</Id>
<Date>2013-08-03T16:00:00+02:00</Date>
<League>Scottish Premier League</League>
<Round>1</Round>
<HomeTeam>Aberdeen</HomeTeam>
<HomeTeam_Id>45</HomeTeam_Id>
<HomeGoals>2</HomeGoals>
<AwayTeam>Kilmarnock</AwayTeam>
<AwayTeam_Id>52</AwayTeam_Id>
<AwayGoals>1</AwayGoals>
<Time>Finished</Time>
<Location>Pittodrie Stadium</Location>
<HomeTeamYellowCardDetails>39': Jonathan Hayes;</HomeTeamYellowCardDetails>
<AwayTeamYellowCardDetails>38': James Fowler;18': Christopher Johnston;</AwayTeamYellowCardDetails>
<HomeTeamRedCardDetails/>
<AwayTeamRedCardDetails/>
</Match>
</XMLSOCCER.COM>
```

and here is my PHP code I have written so far:

```
foreach($response->Match as $match){
        print "{$match->HomeTeam}<br />\n";
        }

    print $response -> {"XMLSOCCER.COM"};
```

But I can't seem to get any output, I keep getting errors such as:

- Undefined property: stdClass::
- Trying to get property of non-object in

I'm just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction with this. At the moment I'd just to like print out a HomeTeam name for example, from here I can progress further.

Comment: Well you have not showed what `$response` is actually. Apart from that the error itself is pretty clear: You are accessing that unsepcified `$response` something *wrong*. So I can only guess you would like to parse XML.

Comment: What's `$response` in all this? Directly from the SOAP system? A DOM/simple_xml object?

Comment: you have possibly forgotten some quotes: try `$response->{"Match"}` instead  of  `$response->Match`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking his $response variable is just that, the RAW response from the API call.  If this is correct you need to load that $response into the PHP **simplexml_load_string** function or load the API call with **simplexml_load_file**, before you can use your variable like an object.  These functions will give you a SimpleXMLElement object back so you can do things like $xml->Match

simplexml_load_string: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

Comment: Firstly, Thank you for your help. Secondly, Now I've added your edit.
`$response = $client->GetFixturesByLeagueAndSeason(array('api_key'=>'Key','season'=>'1314','league'=>'SPL'));
 /*foreach($response->Match as $match)
    {
        print "{$match->HomeTeam}<br />\n";
    }*/
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 print $xml;
`
But now it comes up with this warning:
Warning: simplexml_load_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in

But still now output, Just wondering how to change the object to a string? or will that be a fix to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can parse the xml feed as follows, you might use `simplexml_load_file`

```
$feed_url="your xml feed url";

    $response = simplexml_load_file($feed_url);

    print_r($response);

   foreach($response->Match as $match)
   {
    echo "{$match->HomeTeam}<br />\n";
    }
```